# Why can I not find journalentries using their RefNumber in Quickbooks SDK?

Tags: quickbooks

I boiled this down to a simple example that always fails using QB Enterprise. (Oddly, I could swear this code used to work.)

1. Create a journal entry via SDK with a specific ref number "PTD1234"
2. Search for that specific journal entry in the same code block
3. Observe, no results found?

However, if I change the process to create the same journal entry by hand in QB, then the search code below works correctly and finds the journal entry.

```
        Quickbooks qb = new Quickbooks();
        qb.Connect(this);

        IMsgSetRequest msr = qb.sm.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 7, 0);
        msr.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeStop;

        IJournalEntryAdd jea = msr.AppendJournalEntryAddRq();

        jea.TxnDate.SetValue(new DateTime(2013, 3, 1));
        jea.RefNumber.SetValue("PTD1234");

        IJournalCreditLine jcl = jea.ORJournalLineList.Append().JournalCreditLine;
        jcl.Amount.SetValue(1);
        jcl.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue("Credit Card Batches:Paymentech");
        jcl.EntityRef.FullName.SetValue("CHASE PAYMENTECH");

        IJournalDebitLine jdl = jea.ORJournalLineList.Append().JournalDebitLine;
        jdl.Amount.SetValue(1);
        jdl.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue("Chase Deposits EUR");
        jdl.EntityRef.FullName.SetValue("CHASE PAYMENTECH");

        IMsgSetResponse msp = qb.sm.DoRequests(msr);
        IResponse resp = msp.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
        if (resp.StatusCode != 0)
        {
            Log("-------------\r\nError during test");
            Log(resp.StatusMessage);
        }

        IJournalEntryRet jet = null;

        msr = qb.sm.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 7, 0);
        msr.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeStop;

        IJournalEntryQuery q = msr.AppendJournalEntryQueryRq();
        q.metaData.SetValue(ENmetaData.mdNoMetaData);
        q.ORTxnQuery.TxnFilter.ORRefNumberFilter.RefNumberFilter.RefNumber.SetValue("PTD1234");
        q.ORTxnQuery.TxnFilter.ORRefNumberFilter.RefNumberFilter.MatchCriterion.SetValue(ENMatchCriterion.mcContains);
        q.ORTxnQuery.TxnFilter.AccountFilter.ORAccountFilter.FullNameList.Add("Chase Deposits EUR");
        q.IncludeLineItems.SetValue(false);

        msp = qb.sm.DoRequests(msr);
        if (msp.ResponseList.Count > 0)
        {
            IResponseList rl = msp.ResponseList;
            if (rl.Count >= 1)
            {
                IResponse r = rl.GetAt(0);
                if (r.Detail == null)
                    Log("Fail: Detail was null");

                if (r.StatusCode != 0)
                    Log("Fail: Status code was not zero");

                if (r.Type.GetValue() == (short)ENResponseType.rtJournalEntryQueryRs)
                {
                    IJournalEntryRetList crl = (IJournalEntryRetList)r.Detail;
                    if (crl != null && crl.Count == 1)
                        jet = crl.GetAt(0);
                }
            }
        }

        if (jet != null)
            Log("Success!");

        qb.Cleanup();
```

Comment: @keith I figured. Only problem is Intuit won't look at it if it isn't tagged with the IPP tag...

Comment: You can re-tag if you want, but the better place to post about non-IPP issues is their forums: https://idnforums.intuit.com/

Comment: @KeithPalmer no, your edit is correct. I don't really get what they are doing with their support.

Comment: I don't think they know either. It's the typical Intuit "let's change our minds and **** our developer community over again!" decision. I think they try to do it at least once a year, just to keep us on our toes.

Comment: @KeithPalmer IPP is supposed to be the future, since SDK apps aren't allowed in the store anymore. So strange then that they push IPP to SO, and keep the SDK forum open.

Comment: They keep the SDK open because a) There's a HUGE number of existing apps that use the SDK still, and b) IPP is a pile of crap right now: buggy, unreliable, incomplete and c) There are a lot of apps that IPP doesn't work for (IPP is only for SaaS type apps, so you can't use it for internal integrations/one-off/custom integrations.

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reasons, some journalentries won't show up using a JournalEntryQuery and the TxnFilter.ORRefNumberFilter.RefNumberFilter.  However, a workaround is to use the ORTxnQuery.RefNumberList and then cycle through the Journal Lines and make sure the account matches.

```
   public bool GetExactJournalTransaction(string sRefNum, string sAccount, out IJournalEntryRet jet)
    {
        jet = null;

        IMsgSetRequest msr = sm.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 4, 0);
        msr.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeStop;

        IJournalEntryQuery q = msr.AppendJournalEntryQueryRq();
        q.metaData.SetValue(ENmetaData.mdNoMetaData);
        q.ORTxnQuery.RefNumberList.Add(sRefNum);
        q.IncludeLineItems.SetValue(true);


        IMsgSetResponse resp = sm.DoRequests(msr);
        if (resp.ResponseList.Count == 0)
            return false;

        IResponseList rl = resp.ResponseList;
        if (rl.Count == 1)
        {
            IResponse r = rl.GetAt(0);
            if (r.Detail == null)
                return false;

            if (r.StatusCode != 0)
                return false;

            if (r.Type.GetValue() == (short)ENResponseType.rtJournalEntryQueryRs)
            {
                IJournalEntryRetList crl = (IJournalEntryRetList)r.Detail;
                if (crl != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < crl.Count; i++)
                    {
                        jet = crl.GetAt(i);
                        for (int j = 0; j < jet.ORJournalLineList.Count; j++)
                        {
                            IORJournalLine l = jet.ORJournalLineList.GetAt(j);
                            if (l.JournalCreditLine != null && l.JournalCreditLine.AccountRef.FullName.GetValue() == sAccount)
                                return true;
                            else if (l.JournalDebitLine != null && l.JournalDebitLine.AccountRef.FullName.GetValue() == sAccount)
                                return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```